# How I can get all values of the same query parameter in the postman

Tags: javascript, api, testing, postman

I have the GET request in Postman:

```
/dominance?start={{start}}&end={{end}}&slugs[]=bitcoin-btc&slugs[]=ethereum-eth
```

For writing tests for API call, I need to write in an array all possible values, where the key is "slugs[]"
How I can do it?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how the API is implemented, what the values are and how many they are, you could either have something like

```
/dominance?start={{start}}&end={{end}}&slugs[]=ALL
```

Making all the code edits in the backend, or

```
/dominance?start={{start}}&end={{end}}&slugs[]=bitcoin-btc&slugs[]=ethereum-eth&slugs[]=cardano-ada&slugs[]=tether-tet
```

and so on, but doing so will create a very long URI.

If you have the possibility of editing the backend, I'd do a special case using something like that ALL keyword, or consider creating custom groups.

Comment: Okay, it is my mistake. I need from this query params get the array of "slugs[]" values in postman for tests